# What's the better way to put struct into slice in Go

Tags: go, struct, slice

I have func ***Struct2slice(somestruct Manystrings) []string*** to convert struct of strings into slice of strings. I believe there is better, quicker and simpler way to do it, without import reflect . Is there ?

```
   type Manystrings struct {
        string1 string
        string2 string
        string3 string
    }

func Struct2slice(somestruct Manystrings) []string {

    v := reflect.ValueOf(somestruct)
    values := make([]string, v.NumField())
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        values[i] = v.Field(i).String()
    }
    return values
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can construct a slice of the three strings directly -- there's no need for `reflect`.

```
func (ms *ManyStrings) Strings() []string {
    return []string{ms.string1, ms.string2, ms.string3}
}
```

You can define a method like this for each of the structs you have. That's simple, as fast as it can be, and easy to understand.

If you're concerned about how manually-written methods like this could be inconsistent with the actual struct definitions, I'd probably use the reflection-based solution you have in the question in a unit test, to check that the `Strings()` methods are correct. Something like this:

```
func toStrings(x interface{}) []string {
  v := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(x))
  var r []string
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        r = append(r, v.Field(i).String())
    }
    return r
}

func TestStrings(t *testing.T) {
  egs := []interface{Strings()[]string}{
    &ManyStrings{"one", "two", "three"},
    &ManyStrings{},
    &ManyStrings{"a", "", ""},
    &ManyStrings{"", "b", ""},
    &ManyStrings{"", "", "c"},
    ... any other test cases
  }
  for _, ex := range egs {
    got, want := ex.Strings(), toStrings(ex)
    if !reflect.DeepEqual(got, want) {
      t.Errorf("%v.Strings() = %v, want %v", ex, got, want)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: excellent answer, really appreciate. For that TestStrings I got panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.NumField on ptr Value [recovered] panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.NumField on ptr Value

Comment: Yeah, sorry - I used a pointer receiver for `Strings()` whereas your code used the struct. I added the missing `reflect.Indirect`.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Why would there be? First, your function is only five lines of code, it is already short and simple. Second, converting a struct into a slice of strings is not a "normal" thing to do, at least not enough to mandate making it easier than it already is. As it stands, it is only slightly less convenient than in, say, Javascript or PHP, and that is already quite an achievement for a strongly typed compiled language.